# My camera2 API getting stuck on taking a picture

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am making a camera application using Camera 2 API,my code to show preview works well and it also clicks pictures from the preview and stores them in a directory.
My problem is :
**it is getting stuck while taking the picture and storing it, once the picture is stored the camera works as normal.**

This is my code which take the preview image and stores it:

**onTakePhotoButtonClicked():**

```
public void onTakePhotoButtonClicked() {
    FileOutputStream outputPhoto = null;
    try {
        outputPhoto = new FileOutputStream(createImgFile());
        preview.getBitmap()
                .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputPhoto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outputPhoto != null) {
                outputPhoto.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**createImgFile():**

```
private File createImgFile() throws IOException{

    String TimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String prepend = "IMG_"+TimeStamp+"_";
    File Imgfile = File.createTempFile(prepend,".jpg",mPictureFolder);
    mPictureFileName = Imgfile.getAbsolutePath();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mPictureFileName.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return Imgfile;
}
```

**onCreate():**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_mycamera_experiment);
    preview = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    click = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.click);
    createImgFolder();

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT );

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onTakePhotoButtonClicked();

        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to make taking the photo and getting back to the camera faster?
Any correction,better method?

Comment: @shriyans_varma your question is why your app locked?!

Comment: yes, Its like why is my app getting stuck when the camera button is pressed( onTakePhotoButtonClicked() is called) , and as soon as the picture is taken from preview and stored, the camera is normal. My question is how do i take away this lag and run my camera normally in foreground, while the image gets stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are saving a bitmap in UI thread.
You should save a bitmap in worker thread.

And, If you want to take pictures, you'd better use [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader) Api.
I think saving the bitmap of TextureView is not a good idea.

Comment: Yup,totally makes sense. I am also using ImageReader API . Thanks a lot for your suggestion.